# Android app crashes when using accelerometer sensor

Tags: android, accelerometer, sensors

I want to count the number of steps taken by the user of the android phone (basically i want to implement a basic pedometer). I am using the logic that if the change in acceleration in z direction is greater than some thresold value then it must be counted as one step.

My app uses the following code to use the accelerometer to count the number of steps taken

```
package com.bhaskar.workout_helper_app;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

   public class CountActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {

private float mLastZ,mLastY,mLastX;
private int stepcount;
private TextView tv;
private SensorManager mSensorManager;
private Sensor mAccelerometer;
private Boolean mInitialized;

// constants
private final float LEG_THRSHOLD_AMPLITUDE = (float) 5.0;
private static final float NOISE = (float) 2.0;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.countactivity);

    // initialise variables
    stepcount = 0;
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    mInitialized=false;
    // initialise sensor manager and check whether accelerometer is present
    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mAccelerometer = mSensorManager
            .getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    if (mAccelerometer == null) {
        Log.d("HARDWARE", "ACCELEROMETER NOT PRESENT!!!");
        startActivity(new Intent(CountActivity.this, workoutdata.class));
    } else {
        if (mAccelerometer.getMinDelay() != 0) {
            Log.d("ACCELEROMETER",
                    "reports data only when the value of accelerometer is changed!!!");
            //tv.setText("at regular interval "+SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        }
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer,
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }
    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            tv.setText(stepcount);
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startActivity(new Intent(CountActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (event.sensor.getType() != Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
        return;
    }
    float x = event.values[0];
    float y = event.values[1];
    float z = event.values[2];


    if(Math.abs(z) > LEG_THRSHOLD_AMPLITUDE)
        stepcount++;
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    if (mAccelerometer != null)
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer,
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    if (mAccelerometer != null)
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
}
}
```

But it crashes whenever I test it on my phone please help what should I do?

Comment: do not forget to add crash logs. when app crashes!

Comment: Where does it crash? When you run it in debugger it will show you the exactl line where the exception occurs.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
  tv.setText(""+stepcount);
```

instead of

```
     tv.setText(stepcount);
```